# Running NodeMCU with Arduino

Tags: macos, arduino, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I got my first NodeMCU today and I'm trying to run the blink sketch from Arduino http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Blink

I've installed [ch340G](http://www.wch.cn/download/CH341SER_MAC_ZIP.html) driver (as its mentioned in my nodemcu) and everything went without any errors.

However the problem is, it says the program is uploaded 100%, but the LED is not blinking. I would expect the LED to blink after the upload.

Following is a screen shot of my setup:

[image]

Also, I did bit of googling and I've seen port errors can be caused by poor cables, but I'm using my GoPro cable here.

Comment: There are multiple versions of NodeMCU boards. Which one do you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 leds on the Nodemcu.

It might just be that the second led might be faulty.

Add this at the start of your blink code example

```
#ifdef LED_BUILTIN
#undef LED_BUILTIN
#endif
#define LED_BUILTIN 2
```

This will change the pin number for the builtin led, to the 2nd led on the Nodemcu.

Check if it works. If it does, then the 1st led is probably faulty.

I hope this helps.

Comment: hey @Nitro, `#define LED_BUILTIN 2`, did the trick :) thanks a lot for the help 

Comment: @sameera207: Using pin 2 as the led was just 1 part of my answer. You have to look into the possibility that the other led on your Nodemcu is faulty.

The LED_BUILTIN is set to 16 on the Nodemcu, and that's where the second led is supposed to be connected.

Check this link to know more https://lowvoltage.github.io/2017/07/09/Onboard-LEDs-NodeMCU-Got-Two

Comment: @sameera207: Thanks for supporting my answer, I am new to stack-overflow, and normally delete my posts if they get 2 or more -ve votes.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be loading fine, try restarting the board(reset button).

Maybe the LED is on another pin,
nodeMCU pin numbers do not have to correspond to the ones used in arduino framework, take a look here for a [possible pin mapping, example sketch and schema](http://icircuit.net/using-nodemcu-arduino-ide/1396).

EDIT:
 [LED is on pin D4](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/38979/20378)

Comment: hi @feelingunwelcome, I don't understand your comment, They have given perfectly valid answers and they've given options to check. also, in my screenshot, the code is not visible. So, I believe guessing is a perfectly valid and everyone is trying to help. I think we should appreciate who spend their own time to answer these questions than trying to pick on their answers (and would be appreciate if you can remove the downvote, assuming you did it)

Comment: hey thanks @Martin, it was the Pin number, I got it working by adding  `#define LED_BUILTIN 2`, thanks a lot for the help. I had to pick the Nitro's answer, but I upvoted yours , cheers